# iCloud drive - is it possible to access user files

Tags: ios, iphone, icloud, icloud-drive

I configured my IOS project to work with iCloud drive. Now I'm able to store and read files from my app's ubiquitous container.

Is it however possible to access also files from root directory of iCloud? 
Let's assume the user put some movie file into his iCloud Drive folder on Mac. The movie file can be now seen and downloaded using iCloud Drive application on Iphone. Can I also access this file from my application?

Or, to put it in other way, can I query for and access files uploaded by user to his iCloud root folder?

Edit:
From my investigation it looks that the only way to access these files is using UIDocumentPickerViewController. I didn't find any solution to access the files programatically so that I can filter them and display to user using custom UI.

Comment: Have you found the solution?